# Get Connection string for Pass through queries

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have just learned about the pass through queries in `MS-ACCESS`.

I have a `SQL SERVER` backend and
if I'm right, for a query access loads all records before to do the where clause... so what would be the point of having a `SQL SERVER` backend?

That's why I want to try using pass through queries as much as possible but is there a way I can get the connection string from my linked tables for my pass through queries?

I tried `CurrentDb.TableDefs("One of my table name").Connect` in the `ODBC Connect Str` property but I got the error saying it's an invalid connection string.

It would be nice because I know I will have to change the connection soon so I wouldn't have to edit the connection string at many places.

Thank you.

Comment: For the most part, it is easier to use linked tables. Did you prefix your connection string with `ODBC;`?

Comment: BTW, I can cut and paste from my connected table to the connect property of the pass-through.

Comment: Actually, it works with my connection string. I just wanted to make them update automatically with my linked tables.

Comment: @remou that's why I tried `CurrentDb.TableDefs("One of my table name").Connect`

Comment: I think you need to build the connection string manually (in code) instead of copying it from a table, especially if you are not using a Trusted Connection.

Comment: A visit to http://www.connectionstrings.com will help you find the correct string to use : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant here: "*for a query access loads all records before to do the where clause*"

If the `WHERE` clause can be applied at the server, ODBC will translate it to the server's language, and only the matching rows will be sent back to Access:

```
WHERE date_field >= #2011-01-01# AND date_field < #2012-01-01#
```

That `WHERE` clause would limit the rows sent to Access to only those whose `date_field` values are from 2011.

However, if a `WHERE` clause includes functions which must be evaluated by Access, ODBC must retrieve all candidate rows and hand them over to the Access db engine so it can perform the evaluation.

```
WHERE Format(date_field, 'yyyy') = '2011'
```

But for your actual question ... connection string for pass through queries ... consider the following code example.  I have an ODBC link named `dbo_foo` whose source table in SQL Server is `[dbo].[foo]`.  So I can grab the `.Connect` property from `dbo_foo` and use it for the `.Connect` property of a pass through query based on the same server table.

```
Public Sub CreatePassThruQuery()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strConnect As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strConnect = db.TableDefs("dbo_foo").Connect
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("qryDbo_Foo")
    qdf.Connect = strConnect
    qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[foo];"
    qdf.Close
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Still when you change the `.Connect` property of the table, you will also need to do it for the query.  If you have many of them and/or change the connections frequently, it may be worth the effort to create a VBA procedure to update them.  Alternatively, you might use a DSN for the `.Connect` property of the table and matching query.  Then revise the DSN as needed.  A pitfall with that approach is that, if other people will be using your application, you would need to manage the DSNs on multiple machines.

Comment: I meant this http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1482/microsoft-access-pass-through-queries-to-sql-server/    `When querying a linked table, Access will return/load the entire table into Access before parsing the WHERE or HAVING clauses.  Imagine the implications of querying a large table or data set comprised of multiple tables in Access against a linked SQL Server record source in your environment! `

Comment: that's why I thought it was bad. But I think I will just stick to my easy linked tables cause pass through queries are harder to use with parameters and I don't wanna deal with the connection string in all my code.

Comment: In that article you linked, read the comment from Craig Yellick (Friday, July 22, 2011 - 2:23:33 PM).

Comment: As noted, the advice about Access always pulling all rows is WRONG. If you have an standard linked table (not pass through) to SQL server then you can open this standard BOUND form with a simple where clause such as invoice # and despite that form being bound to the SQL server table with 1 million rows Access will ONLY PULL THE ONE ROW from SQL server based on that "where" clause.